# PHP: Handling quotes before PDO exec

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo, simplexml

I have a form that I designed and my intent is to accept any UTF-8 content and insert it into MySQL database. I have used PDO with charset utf-8 as encoding for connecting to database. The insert query is still failing when content has characters such as single-quotes. What in-built function should I be using on my input content before using it on query. Below is the sample query that is formed just before being inserted into database

```
    INSERT INTO dbname.table 
               (input_xml) 
           VALUES 
               ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
            <ip_Input>
                 <ip_xml>
                    Qaiku.com – What Can We 
                    Learn From Failure?By Guest Blogger, September 11, 2012, Leave a 
                    CommentEditor's note: I think we in the tech press have the tendency to 
                    focus on the positive stories and forget about the startups that didn't live up 
                    their expectations. Our Sofanatics coverage this past week has been one of the 
                    few times we've covered abandoned projects, which is a pitty because there are a 
                    lot to learn from "failures." Below we have a long read from Eero Holmila which 
                    is one part eulogy, and another part what he's learned from the now-announced 
                    shutdown of Qaiku.com.Qaiku.com might be a familiar name for some of the 
                    readers of Arctic Startup. However, I am quite sure that the background and the 
                    rough road from high hopes to a bitter decline probably is not. I am the CEO of 
                    Rohea, a company behind a handful of quite successful Finnish websites like 
                    Kotikokki.net, Kuvake.net, Mikseri.net and of course a less successful 
                    Qaiku.com.I am going to share some lessons learned through the trip. I hope 
                    some of it might be of use, spark up ideas or if nothing else, be at least a bit 
                    entertaining. One last important disclaimer: all the opinions are my own.Now 
                    without further delay, this is the story of 
                    Qaiku.
                </ip_xml>
           </ip_Input>
              ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you should be using is [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). Before doing so, you also should read up on SQL Injection and the proper way to use PDO with parameterized queries.